# Where do crash reports appear?

Tags: android, google-play

My Android app crashed and I sent a crash report along with a system log to the developer.

So... where is the crash report? I have been to ANRs & crashes in the Google Play Console and there's nothing there?

If they appear there, how long does it take?

Comment: They do appear there, under the "Crashes" tab obviously. I am looking at one now that was sent 1h30m ago, so it should take less than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app wasn't installed from the Play Store, then you may not see the crash in the Play Console. They get filtered out.